# Update record in salesforce from Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Currently I have my salesforce org and Markting cloud integrated using Marketing Cloud Connect.Is there a way if I update any contact information (ex:Subscribtion details) in Marketing Cloud , I can update the same in salesforce.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accept it so others can see that your question has been answered statisfactorily.

Answer (score 4):

Currently the synchronization via the connector only works unidirectional. As far as I know the only way to update data in the sales/service cloud is using the Sales & Service Cloud Activities or a Custom Activity that accesses the salesforce api in a Journey.

http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/canvas_activities/activities_reference/

Additionally you can update a Salesforce Object via AMPScript: http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_functions_for_use_with_salesforcecom/updatesinglesalesforceobject52/

Comment: Does this overwrite the subscriber key to the salesforceID upon creation?  Or would the newly created contact be injected as a net new contact via MCC on the synchronization schedule?

Comment: If you use a journey activity or AMPscript to create a new Contact-record in Sales Cloud, this is a separate object. The subscriber used in the journey won't be changed/updated with the ID of the new record. Once you use the new Contact in a journey, this record's ID is also used as SubscriberKey. If you just update a record, the ID doesn't change in Sales Cloud, so there is no change in SubscriberKey, as no new ID in Sales Cloud is introduced.

Answer (score 0):

A third option for updating data in Sales/Service Cloud is by mapping profile attributes to fields on the Lead or Contact Object.

http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/exacttarget_salesforce_integration_v2_non_enterprise_2_0/attributes_for_salesforce_leads_and_contacts_procedures/

Answer (score 0):

There are two options: 
**1**. AMPScript:

```
%%[ var @id
set @id=CreateSalesforceObject('lead', 2, 'FirstName', 'Chris', 'LastName', 'Cruz')
]%%

%%[ var @result set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Lead','00Q00003yAEj','Email','jcc@example.com') ]%%
```

**2**. Journey Builder: 'Sales and server cloud' activities

[image]