# How to send subscriber behavioral data back from SFMC to object in Sales Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

**Scenario:**

Marketer creates a journey in SFMC that triggers on new Contact object created in Sales Cloud (Contact is treated as SFMC Subscriber, SFMC connector is in place). I want to be able to send back that Contact email behavior (data views information) performed in Journey back to Sales Cloud with possibility to see individual actions of that subscriber (emails sent, opened, links clicked etc).

I'm thinking I would start by setting up a tracking extract or querying data views and then move that data from either Enchanced FTP or data extension to Sales Cloud. Am I approaching it right or is there a easier way to do it? If my suggested approach is prefered one - how to move that data from DE or FTP to SC?

Comment: Follow below link https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145849/update-record-in-salesforce-from-marketing-cloud/198357#198357

Comment: Follow below link
<br><br>
[https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145849/update-record-in-salesforce-from-marketing-cloud/198357#198357](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145849/update-record-in-salesforce-from-marketing-cloud/198357#198357)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question Tracking and Analytics are returned to Service Cloud by the Connector.

http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/tracking/

Comment: I missed those objects. Checked them and ran into another problem - they aren't populated with any data with Aggregate Link Level Details and Business Unit being exception. I assume since aggregated information is sent back, the individual should be sent as well? Or am I missing something again?

Comment: There are a few things I'd check. Did you do a Salesforce Send? Did you check the "Send Salesforce Tracking Data" checkbox? Is the Sending DE in the Salesforce Data Extensions folder?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible OOTB unless you can achieve it by data extension using SOAP or REST but if you use Triggered Email Send from Sales/Service Cloud then you can achieve this by writing trigger over contact/lead objects. Whenever a record is created or updated you can trigger transactional emails from Sales/Service cloud and use Marketing Cloud as your email server. This way MC Connector will track all out going mails plus analytics (clicks, email sent, link opened) and to whom you sent those emails i.e. contact or leads.

Here is the [link](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/sending_emails/triggered_sends/configure_objects_and_triggers/) for more info.